# Why does `svn status` show ignored files but not ignored dirs?

Tags: svn, command-line

If I type `svn status` in my working copy, I get a list of all modified files (marked with M) AND all new unversioned files (marked with ?) AND all ignored unversioned files (also marked with ?). Ignored folders are not shown.

That is not very nice because I cannot differ between "new unversioned files" and "ignored unversioned files"!

If I type `svn status -q` (--quiet) then all files marked with "?" are not shown.

If I type `svn status --no-ignore` then I get all files descripted above and all ignored folders (marked with I).

The question is: Why are my ignored files marked with "?" instead of "I"? What is the command to list

- all new, unversioned files
- all modified files
- AND hide all ignored files (folders AND directories)

Comment: @TepkenVannkorn Yes, me too! But i cannot at this time. Migration is planed but not finished.

Comment: @TepkenVannkorn this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the case on Subversion 1.8.8 (and would be very annoying!). Perhaps try upgrading or double-checking that those files are indeed ignored. It sounds like they are not.

In 1.8.8, `svn status` shows:

- `M` for modified files
- `?` for new files

but no ignored files.

Then `svn status --no-ignore` shows:

- `M` for modified files
- `?` for new files
- `I` for ignored files and folders

For example:

```
$ svn status
M       README.md
?       newfile
$ svn status --no-ignore
I       .flows.json.backup
M       README.md
I       config/__init__.pyc
I       config/__pycache__
?       newfile
```

Where `.flows.json.backup` and `__init__.pyc` are files and `config/__pycache__` is a folder.